# Finding all points a distance from particular lat long java

Tags: java, csv, data-structures, io

I have a csv file with a bunch of lat long coordinates. I also have a csv file with a bunch of positions that a particular person will be standing at.  For each of the points in the second file, I need to figure out whether they are near (under 1 mile) any of the points in the first file. I have about 500 points in each of the files.

I'm trying to solve this in Java, and I thought I would use something along the lines of read the first file in and putting it in some sort of structure that is easily searchable, this way I do not need to keep doing IO operations.  I'm unclear as to what type of data structure I should hold the points in so that I can easily search for ones that are within a radius of a given point. Could someone point me in the right direction? Is there any way that I can organize this so that I don't need to make n^2 comparisons?

Comment: Do you intend to use spherical trigonometry?  Or is plane geometry accurate enough for your purposes?

Comment: @DavidWallace He doesn't seem to be asking about the method for finding the distance actually.  I was thinking this at first too.

Comment: I know what he's asking.  But the reason that I asked my question was to figure out how much sorting/structuring overhead is worthwhile, to cut down on calculations.  The spherical calculation is very complex, and worth going a long way to avoid.  The plane calculation less so.

Comment: However, thinking about it "a mile apart in plane distance" is VERY close to being equivalent to "a mile apart on a great circle".  For any practical purpose, the difference isn't worth worrying about.  So we can probably treat this as a plane geometry problem.

Comment: I would use a rectangle to calculate the points. Do you know any device that have a circular display?

Comment: @JackTools He never says that he's going to display a graphic.  It seems to be the actual numeric calculation that he's interested in.  If there is a wide range of different latitudes in his data, then plane geometry won't give him accurate distances.

Comment: Plane geometry is accurate enough, I'm more interested in how to reduce the amount of scans through each list, it seems silly to read each point from list b and then have to read each point from list a for each of those points.  I'm thinking that there has to be some kind of data structure that I can put list A into so that it would be easier to search through, someone recommended a concept called spatial hashing but I'm unsure if that is a preferred way to do this, is there something else that would give me a logarithmic way to search for list of points within a radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to store your points in a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) based on latitude and longitude.

If we know that we want all points within some set distance `D` of some point `(lat, lon)`, it's simple to calculate the difference in latitude `d_lat` corresponding to `D` units of distance due north/south, and the difference in longitude `d_lon` corresponding to `D` units of distance due east/west at whichever of latitudes `lat-d_lat` or `lat+d_lat` is closest to a pole.  Using this we perform an [orthogonal range search](http://cosmopedia.net/Kd-tree#Orthogonal_range_search_in_a_kd-tree) in the tree for all points with latitude between `lat-d_lat` and `lat+d_lat` and longitude between `lon-d_lon` and `lon+d_lon`.  We then need to calculate the distance for each of these, and reject ones over `D` away from `(lat, lon)` - but we won't need to do as many calculations as without the tree (we should only end up rejecting roughly 1-pi/4 = 21.5% of points that get to this stage).

Of course you'll need to account for edge cases, if they're relevant to you:

- If you're within `d_lon` of 180 degrees longitude, you'll need to do two different searches in the tree (either side of 180 degrees).
- If `(lat, lon)` is within `d_lat` latitude of a pole, just look for everything north/south of whichever of `lat-d_lat` or `lat+d_lat` is farthest from the pole.

Comment: This sounds most elegant to me thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do.

Sort all the points in both files in order of latitude.  Then iterate through both lists at the same time, so that for each point in file 1, you get a list of points in file 2 whose latitude circle is within one mile of the point from file 1.  You can probably use the `subList` method of `List` somewhere along the way here.

Still within the context of the point from file 1, filter out the points from that sublist whose longitude differs from point 1 by more than one mile.  You'll then have pairs of points that are both within a mile's longitude and within a mile's latitude of each other.

For each such pair, do the exact calculation to see if they really are within a mile "real distance" of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a coarse grid and bucketize your points from the first list into the grid cells. You need to compute a cell "id" for each point and put in into a hash table based on that id.
Once you have that, you can easily lookup nearby points for a given lat/long by finding the right cell and enumerating its content (and the content of the neighboring cells).
The trick is to convert a lat/long into a cell id. One way is to round up the lat/long. So, for example, convert (47.43402067, -121.89068567) pair into a "47_-121" string. This can be too rough because one degree is approximately 70 mile at equator. You can tighten it up by rounding to a certain decimal point:
e.g. "47.43_-122.89".
Note that cells width is going to narrow down as you going further north or south. For example at 60 degrees North the cell is going to be two times more narrow than at equator (it will only cover 35 miles).

You can also use existing geospatial indexes from libraries like JTS Topology Suite which allow much more flexibility.